# Hover property applies to child

Tags: css, box-shadow, descendant

Good day everyone, i have been trying to apply `box-shadow` property to a webpage but if i apply the effect to the normal state, everything works fine but on the hover state, if i hover on the child, it applies to both the parent and the child.

Normal state: everything works fine
[image: Normal State]

hover state: property applies to each element in the div
[image: Hover state]

I have tried using `Jquery` to toggle the state but it does not work.

**HTML**

```
<div class="results">
  <div class="result_wrapper">
    <div class="result">
      <h2 class="single"><a href="#"><font size="4dp">A title</font></a></h2>
      <div class="single">shortDiscription</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.result {
  background-color: #fff0f0;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 1%;
  width: 600px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px grey;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.myClmass :hover {
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px grey;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.singleHover {
  all: revert;
}

.results {
  float: left;
}

.vid {
  float: right;
  margin: 1%;
}

.vidHeader {
  background-color: #d69797;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 400px;
  padding-left: 5%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

This is my java servlet code:

```
 out.println("<div class=\"results\">");
                for(Element post : results){
                    String link = post.childNode(0).childNode(0).absUrl("href");
                    String title = post.getElementsByTag("a").text();
                    String shortDiscription = post.getElementsByClass("b_caption").get(0).child(1).toString();
                    out.println("<div class=\"result_wrapper\" >");
                    out.println("<div class=\"result\">");
                    out.println("<h2 class=\"single\"><a href=\""+link+"\"><font size=\"4dp\">"+title+"</font></a></h2>");
                    out.println("<div class=\"single\">"+shortDiscription+"</div>");
                    out.println("</div></div>");
                }
                out.println("</div>");
```

Comment: We need your code to help you with the problem.

Comment: Show the actual output that was send to the browser, and most importantly the relevant part of your css code, containing your `:hover`.

Comment: You should not show your server side code for such problems but the relevant html code that is send to the client. You should not expect that someone tries to figure out how your server side code composes your actual html code you send to the client. So if you have similar questions in future, check the source code in your browser and post the relevant parts here.

Comment: Thanks, i will take note next time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selector `.myClmass :hover` means that the rule is applied to all descendant elements of the element with the class `myClmass` where the mouse is actually over. So your rule is applied to all elements that are within the element with the class `myClmass`

If you want to apply the box shadow to the element with the class `myClmass` then the selector has to be `.myClmass:hover` without the space between `.myClmass` and `:hover`

Comment: Thanks alot, this was the issue

Comment: Thanks a lot .This is very new to me.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this concept was really helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Try `pointer-events:none`; on your child element in your css

Comment: While this would probably solve the problem, it is more a workaround, because the problem should not occur if the OP uses `:hover` correctly.

Comment: @t.niese you're right but it seems that collins don't know how to use the hover property and he didn't gave us his CSS so its seems to be the only way to help him right now

Comment: @collins do you have a CSS file ?

Comment: Yes, am about to add the whole css and html file

Comment: Okay so you must add in your child element class `pointer-events:none;`